# Contador desde diferentes botones

Tags: c#, asp.net

tengo la función para realizar dos diferentes contadores uno de suma y otra de resta dependiendo del valor que haya en el campo de texto.

```
 protected void Button_Entrar(object sender, EventArgs e){

    bool validUser = validarUsuario.validarU(variableAuxiliarUser.Text.Trim(), variableAuxiliarPass.Text.Trim(),
                                            variableAuxiliarPin.Text.Trim(),Ets.ReportID, out loginValidado, out error);
if (validUser)        
{  
    int i= Convert.ToInt32(Application["contador"]);
    i++;
    Application["contador"] = i;

    txtNpersonas.Text = i.ToString(); 
 Log.insertarComentario("","Contador", txtNpersonas.Text);

    Response.Redirect("../../webtrak/report/view.aspx?ReportKey=CNTR_TIEMPO&ShowMenu=0"); 
}
}
}

  protected void Button_Salir(object sender, EventArgs e){

   if (validarUsuario.validarU(this.variableAuxiliarUser.Text.Trim(), this.variableAuxiliarPass.Text.Trim(),
this.variableAuxiliarPin.Text.Trim(),Ets.ReportID, out loginValidado, out error))        
 {  
  i--;
  this.txtNpersonas.Text = Conversor.convertirString(i); 
     this.Response.Redirect(string.Format("../../webtrak/report/view.aspx?ReportKey=CNTR_TIEMPO&ShowMenu=0")); 

    }
}
```

Aquí esta el campo de texto del cual dependerá el contador.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNpersonas" style="font-size:25px; width:150px;"   runat="server"/>
```

Comment: Y cual seria el problema??? a parte de que solo parece que va de 1 a 2 o de 1 a 0 y nada mas?

Answer (score 0):

Estas desarrollando web, los valores de las variables no se conservan entre request, para mantener el valor de la variable `i` debes conservar esta en el objeto `Session`, `ViewState` o si es una variable para todo el sitio en el `Application`

Si es global tambien podrias definir la variable como `static`, pero no lo recomendaria por temas de bloqueos al acceder de forma concurrente

```
protected void Button_Entrar(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool validUser = validarUsuario.validarU(variableAuxiliarUser.Text.Trim(), variableAuxiliarPass.Text.Trim(),
                                                variableAuxiliarPin.Text.Trim(),Ets.ReportID, out loginValidado, out error);
    if (validUser)        
    {  
        int i= Convert.ToInt32(Application["contador"]);
        i++;
        Application["contador"] = i;

        txtNpersonas.Text = i.ToString(); 
        Response.Redirect("../../webtrak/report/view.aspx?ReportKey=CNTR_TIEMPO&ShowMenu=0"); 
    }
}
```

En el ejemplo de codigo use el objeto `Application` para obtener y asignar la variable, asi tendra el valor en el proximo request

[ASP.NET Session State Overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178581(v%3Dvs.100))

[How to: Save Values in Application State](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/94xkskdf(v=vs.100))

Comment: Ya he introducido el codigo y no se lo traga no reconoce la variable.

Comment: Podrias explicarte mejor, que codigo has introducido? que seria eso de tragar? nunca escuche que el codigo tragara algo, a que variable haces referencia? se suponia que uses un objeto de asp.net como ser el Session o Application

Comment: actualizo el codigo para más información.

Comment: Se supone que en `Button_Salir` tienes que aplicar la misma tecnica. La variable global `i` ya no aplica si usas el Application. Estas entendiendo que son estos objeto de asp.net, o solo copias y pegas el codigo sin entender lo que haces realmente?

Comment: La verdad que esa función Application no la entiendo. Aplicando esta función sin declarar una variable global sería suficiente entiendo.

Comment: Application no es ninguna funcion, es un objeto de asp.net. Exacto no necesitas ninguna variable global, solo necesitas una local donde poner el valor que recuperas para poder sumerle uno y volver asignar para guardarlo y ser usado en el proximo request. Leiste el link que propuse donde explica sobre el tema, o si es que te interesa no buscaste ninguna informacion sobre que son los objetos Session y Application? son objetos basico en el desarrollo web en asp.net

Comment: He realizado un log. ya que no me muestra el valor de la variable. 2020-05-01_10:54:07 -- Informacion
Clase: 
metodo: Contador
descripcion: 3